# setuid() return -1 when specified user ID is the same as the effective user ID

Tags: c, macos, unix

I've compiled a binary `Authorization` and here's its permission

> -rwsr-sr-x  1 root  wheel  18464 10 26 22:07 ./Authorization

I ran it with the root permission

> sudo ./Authorization

so in the beginning, the **uid(real uid)** and **euid(effective uid)** of my process is

> **uid**:0 **euid**:0

then my program would invoke **seteuid(501)** to change the **euid**, now it's

> **uid**:0 **euid**:501

At last, my program would invoke **setuid(501)**, I expected the result is

> **uid:501** **euid: 501**

According to manual of of **setuid**()

> The setuid() function is permitted if the effective user ID is that of the super
>        user, **or if the specified user ID is the same as the effective user ID.**

However, **setuid(501)** return -1 which is not expected, and not the behavior described in the manual, **WHY**??

**Here's my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    printf("uid: %d euid: %d\n", getuid(), geteuid());

    if (seteuid(501) == -1) {
        printf("seteuid error\n");
    }
    printf("seteuid(501)> uid: %d euid: %d\n", getuid(), geteuid());

    if (setuid(501) == -1) {
        printf("setuid error\n");
    }
    printf("setuid(501)> uid: %d euid: %d\n", getuid(), geteuid());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code on my macOS (10.12.6) and the error is `EPERM` (Operation not permitted).

Not sure if the macOS's man page is out of date. On my macOS, the `setuid`'s man page is still of `June 4, 1993`.

---

On Linux (Debian 8.9), `setuid`'s man page says:

> `setuid()` sets the **effective user ID** of the calling process.  **If the effective UID of the caller is root**, the real UID and saved set-user-ID are also set.

The [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/) (2nd edition) book (`8.11 Changing User IDs and Group IDs`) says:

> **Only a superuser process can change the real user ID.** Normally, the real user ID is set by the `login(1)` program when we log in and never changes. Because login is a superuser process, it sets all three user IDs when it calls setuid.

The [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html#tag_16_531_08) (SUSv4) says:

> The various behaviors of the `setuid()` and `setgid()` functions when called by non-privileged
> processes reflect the behavior of different historical implementations. **For portability, it is
> recommended that new non-privileged applications use the `seteuid()` and `setegid()` functions instead.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try to figure it out using the classic error explanation.
To do that you can add some code to the section:

```
 if (setuid(501) == -1) {
    printf("setuid error\n");
    printf ("Error while setting uid: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Dont forget to add these headers:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

Good luck!